# How to find element inside prepend using variables

Tags: jquery

Using jquery 1.3.2. I try to use following construct in jquery but it is not working. No errors in console. Is that ok syntax? 
The action is following: upon clicking a button, It finds an image(clones it) and appends it to another image, which is found by looking at buttons parent with class "top-parent" and then looking inside for image inside element with class(wrapID...).

This is just the appending part of code:

```
prependTo( $(this).closest(".top-parent").find(".wrapID-" + productIDVal + " img"))
```

Thank you for advice

Comment: Might be time to use a jQuery from within the last six years.

Comment: @j08691 thank you for answer to my question ;)

Comment: You cannot append/prepend content to an image. Did you mean `.before()` -http://api.jquery.com/before/`?

Comment: @PeterKA that was it:) thank you.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into the question. If you have an answer, post it as an answer using the form below.

Comment: @meagar ok sorry, so it is PeterKa's turn then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition images are not container tags; therefore content cannot be `appended/prepended` to them. However, you can insert content before or after using the methods `before()` or `after()`:

Try:

```
.....before( $(this).closest(".top-parent").find(".wrapID-" + productIDVal + " img") );
```

[.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)